# input[file] is not focusable when wrapped inside Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to change the default file[input] look. so i have wrapped inside a label like this

```
<label class="btn upload-dir-btn btn-file">
Browse <input type="file" required id="dir-pic-file" name="dir-pic-file" novalidate>
</label>
```

i do some validation when the form is submitted. But when i get the error

> An invalid form control with name='dir-pic-file' is not focusable.

Here is the css to hide the default file

```
#dir-pic-file{
display: none;
```

}

but if i remove the css it works fine. Here is my validation

```
$('#add-dir-form').on('submit',function(e){

  var file = $('#dir-pic-file').val();
    if (file = '') {
        $('#pic-error').css({'display':'block'});
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox allows you to operate the file input when in `display:none`, Chrome on the other hand doesn't unfortunately. It needs to be either `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0` then moved off the page so it doesn't get in the way. See Snippet using `visibility:hidden` and `position:absolute;` Test it with both browsers by clicking the red arrow (it may take a few times because I put the arrow in close proximity, it's like at the tip...) Ok, updated now it's obvious.

```js
$('#add-dir-form').on('submit', function(e) {

  var file = $('#dir-pic-file').val();
  if (file = '') {
    $('#pic-error').css({
      'display': 'block'
    });
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative
}

#dir-pic-file {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* or opacity:0;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: -500px;
}

.btn-file {
  border: 3px inset black;
  position: absolute top:50px;
  left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.btn-file::before {
  content: '\1f882';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  line-height: .6
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn upload-dir-btn btn-file">
Browse <input type="file" required id="dir-pic-file" name="dir-pic-file" novalidate>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for changing the styles of the input you need not to put it in label tag. You can style it using **input[type="file"]** in your css.

Try not to use **display: none;** since it will hide the input from the DOM tree, so you cannot access it, use some other css for it.

Comment: Even if an HTML5 element is on display none you can access it with javascript

Comment: Yes, we can access it. But for type=file, we need element to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

am not sur but maybe you forget the for attribute in label and remove the required

```
    <label for="dir-pic-file" class="btn upload-dir-btn btn-file">

<label class="btn upload-dir-btn btn-file">
Browse <input type="file" id="dir-pic-file" name="dir-pic-file" novalidate>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a control `display:none`, the html5 doesn't understand how to validate the control. And if you are validating it through javascript or jquery and you are making it `display:none`, then you should remove `required` from it. so make it like this.

```
<label for="dir-pic-file" class="btn upload-dir-btn btn-file">
Browse <input type="file" id="dir-pic-file" name="dir-pic-file"  novalidate>
</label>
```